# Uploading XML file into mysql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xml

---

Here is my most current code that is not sending any values to the database but doesnt report any errors.

```
 foreach($library->time_report as $project){
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO instancetable (project_ID,          project_status, client_ID, project_start_time, project_end_time, project_total_time, employee_ID, employee_name, date_created, date_modified, created_by, client_name, priority, organization, number_of_required_types) 
            VALUES ('{$project->project_ID}',{$project->project_status}, '{$project->client_ID}', {$project->project_start_time}, '{$project->project_end_time}', '{$project->project_total_time}','{$project->employee_ID}', {$project->employee_name}, {$project->date_created}, {$project->date_modified}, {$project->created_by}, {$project->client_name}, {$project->priority}, {$project->organization}, {$project->number_of_required_types}");
```

}

I need to upload an XML file into mysql.  It says it is sucessfully uploading, but it just puts a value of 0 in the table. Heres my code:

```
<?php

     echo "starting <br><br>";
     //mysql connection
$con2 = mysql_connect("localhost","test","test");
if (!$con2)  {  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());  }
$selectdb = mysql_select_db("test", $con2);
if (!$selectdb)  { die('Database not used: ; ' . mysql_error());  }

echo "connected to DB<br/><br/>";

 //simplexml load xml file   
$library =  simplexml_load_file('http://localhost/instance.xml');

echo "xml loaded<br/><br/>";

//loop through parsed xmlfeed and print output      

foreach ($library->message as $message) {                  
printf("project_ID: %s\n", $project_ID->project_ID);                  
}

echo "xml parsed<br/><br/>";

//insert into databse                     
mysql_query("INSERT INTO instancetable (project_ID)
VALUES ('project_ID')")
or die(mysql_error());

echo "inserted into mysql<br/><br/>";

//show updated records            
printf ("Records inserted: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());  



//close connection 
mysql_close($con2);
echo " <br /> Finished "
?>
```

So this is the out put I get:

```
starting 

connected to DB

xml loaded

xml parsed

inserted into mysql

Records inserted: 1 
Finished
```

XML File:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<project>
<time_report>
    <project_ID>4</project_ID>
    <project_status>Closed</project_status>
    <client_ID>6001</client_ID>
    <time_record>
        <project_start_time>13:03:19.000</project_start_time>
        <project_end_time>13:14:26.000</project_end_time>
        <project_total_time>0.0104166666666667</project_total_time>
    </time_record>
    <employee_ID>10001</employee_ID>
    <employee_name>Mary Beth</employee_name>
    <date_created>2009-07-02</date_created>
    <date_modified>2009-11-24</date_modified>
    <created_by>Mary Beth</created_by>
    <client_name>BlackRock Funds</client_name>
    <priority/>
    <organization/>
    <number_of_required_types>9999999999</number_of_required_types>
</time_report>
```

The XML file is shown above, it is much larger so I took just one entry out.

Comment: What is it you expect this to do?  `mysql_query("INSERT INTO instancetable (project_ID) VALUES ('project_ID')")`

Comment: insert the project_ID elements from the XML file into the table under the column project_ID

Comment: `'project_ID'` is a string not a variable change it to `'$project_ID'`

Comment: @Benjamin Papp i tried that before and it did not work

Comment: @Benjamin Papp after doing that I get the following error: "Notice: Undefined variable: project_ID in C:\xampp\htdocs\databaseold.php on line 27"

Comment: Show your XML or we cant help. Your foreach loop seems to be wrong too

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<project>
 <time_report>
  <project_ID>4</project_ID>
  <project_status>Closed</project_status>
  <client_ID>6001</client_ID>
  <time_record>

Comment: @BenjaminPaap I added it above

Comment: @BenjaminPaap I want to bring every element into the database.  I just started with one to get it working. Not sure if this extra info helps.

Comment: @BenjaminPapp not sure whats going on now, nothing is being sent to the database.  I even tried removing the other entries :(

Comment: Its saying Records inserted: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$project_ID is not set. The foreach loop probably runs but since $project_ID is not defined it doesn't output anything.

If you want to insert and print each project ID you need the insert query inside the foreach loop.

```
foreach($library->time_report as $project){
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO instancetable (project_ID) 
    VALUES ('{$project->project_ID}')");

  printf("project_ID: %s\n", $project->project_ID);
}
```

Note that project_ID is being inserted as a string here. If the database field is an integer you should remove the single quotes surrounding `$project->project_ID`.

Comment: almost there, I tried to add another element and it stopped working.  I'm sure I did something wrong.  I need to actually import every element in the xml file. Heres my new code:

Comment: foreach ($library->message as $message) {                  
printf("project_ID: %s\n", $project_ID->project_ID, $project_status->project_status);                  
}foreach($library->time_report as $project){
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO instancetable (project_ID, project_status) 
    VALUES ('{$project->project_ID}', '{$project->project_status}')");

  printf("project_ID: %s\n", $project->project_ID);
}

Comment: Is there any easy way to just import every single element without writing each one out?

Comment: I inserted my most recent code at the very top thats giving me problems

Comment: The time values you're trying to access are in a node within the time_report node so they'll show up inside the `time_record` object within `$project` in the foreach loop. Try `$project->time_record->project_start_time`.

Comment: Regarding your question about an easy way to import everything, I think the short answer is no. You could write some code to loop through the object ($library) and get all the key/value pairs then generate the sql query using that but if the scope of your project is only to import this data, I think this is the fastest, easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you only want to insert the last project_ID or all in that file. Try this to insert every project_ID in your XML file.

Try this:

```
foreach ($library->message as $message) { 
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO instancetable (project_ID) VALUES ('" . $message->time_report->project_ID . "')");
}
```

And please note that all mysql_* functions are marked as deprecated. You should learn about [PDO](http://php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php).

Comment: after doing that I get the following error:" Notice: Undefined variable: project_ID in C:\xampp\htdocs\databaseold.php on line 26

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\databaseold.php on line 26
inserted into mysql"

Comment: Papp I inserted my most recent code at the very top thats giving me problems

Comment: What does `mysql_error()` after your query say? You are missing at least a brace at the end of your query.